# Mac Pro Windows won't allow use of 2nd CPU Socket

Tags: windows-10, mac, processor-socket

Two days ago, I purchased a Mac Pro 2006 (1,1) from a local Apple repair shop. The intent was to install my GTX 1050 ti, run windows, and have slightly better hardware than my old i3 550.

I got the pc home, and immediately dropped my SSD from my old PC and my 1050 ti in the mac, booted up using BIOS emulation, and everything seemed to work fine. However I noticed a decent amount of boot up lag. I decided to check Task Manager and found that it was only reporting one of the Xeon 5150's as being used (1 socket, 2 cores, 2 threads).

I've been non-stop googling for the last 2 days, trying to figure out why Windows only wants to use one socket. The first issue was licensing. My old PC was Win 10 Home. So I upgraded to Pro. Still no dice. Someone suggested seeing if the cpu's even show up in Device Manager; They do.

[image: Task Manager and Device Manager Screenshot]

Now I'm at a loss. Both CPU's work in OS X 10.7.5, they both show up in device manager, I have the correct Windows license to support multiple sockets, yet I still only have use of one out of the two sockets. Does anyone have any ideas I can try?

-Edit- I should mention that my old PC was using BIOS, not EFI, which is why I chose to drop the drive in and boot in BIOS emulation mode.

[image: Speccy and CPU-Z]

Comment: You can just go swapping major hardware and expect Windows work properly, re-install windows clean on the new hardware.

Comment: I was considering trying that, however I've actually had no issues in the past swapping the drive between several different computers. There was even a guide that claimed installing x64 windows on this machine should be done on a second computer, then swapping the drive back in. I'll try installing fresh on a 2nd drive tonight.

Comment: Windows just doesn't do well when major hardware is introduced after installation, sometimes you can get lucky and sometimes it will not even boot.

Comment: [What does msconfig show?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/cant-enable-my-second-processor-core/98e7e447-ebd7-4c08-a5ab-cc89e12ba663)

Comment: It reports 2 CPU's https://gyazo.com/a1267b27e30056cb85980d87bb4f3192

Answer (score 2):

Moab was correct, Re-installing windows fixed the issue. Just previous to that, I took a windows server 2008r2 HDD out of a core 2 duo machine and booted it on the mac, which showed both CPU's, so I am under the assumption that I had just moved that windows installation around too many times.

Comment: Another explanation that would fit your experience would be a bug in the upgrade process from home to pro not correctly lifting the socket count restriction.